# Cant find a way to open AppData/LocalLow directory

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I am able to get path to User 'AppData/Local' folder as follows. 
appdatafile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]. getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties). get("LocalAppData", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path;

Can anyone help me to get the 'AppData/LocalLow' user folder?

Answer (score 0):

There's this trick on top of my head. If your component is installed in user's profile folder of Firefox, you can use built-in _____LOCATION_____ string to get location of your component and then navigate few folders upwards to get AppData folder.

Comment: There's no space between ____ and LOCATION____, but I had to insert it otherwise this editor interprets it as bold.